# Common Lisp: Efficiently handling supplied-p-parameter efficiently without using &rest arguments

Tags: performance, common-lisp

Suppose I have the function

```lisp
(defun bar (a &optional (b nil bp))
  (declare (ignore a b bp)) ; <-- replace it with (list a b bp)
                            ;     to check for correctness
  )
;; I want to preserve the value of bp here inside bar, and inside foo below
```

and I wish to write a wrapper around `bar`:

```lisp
(defun foo (a &optional (b nil bp))
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (apply #'bar a (nconc (when bp (list b)))))
```

while preserving the value of `bp` in the call from `foo` to `bar`, and also keeping the arguments `b` visible in the emacs' minibuffer / eldoc-mode. I wanted to know if there's a possibly-nonportable non-consing way to preserve the value of `bp` in this call.

For example,

```lisp
CL-USER> (time (loop repeat 1000000 do (foo 4 2)))
Evaluation took:
  0.040 seconds of real time
  0.043656 seconds of total run time (0.043656 user, 0.000000 system)
  110.00% CPU
  96,380,086 processor cycles
  15,990,784 bytes consed <--- plenty of consing
  
NIL
```

If I ignore the `b`-visibility-in-eldoc, I could possibly use `&rest` arguments, but I do want the arguments to be visible.

While there are other ways to achieve this in this particular case, I do want to consider the case when there are multiple &optional (or &keyword) arguments.

Comment: Why are you using `nconc`? Just write `(apply #'bar a (when bp (list b))))`.

Comment: @adabsurdum In this particular example, nconc has no relevance, yes; when I wrote it I intended it for the case when there could be multiple optional arguments, say another `(c nil cp)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `cond` form to decide how to call `bar`:

```
(defun bar (a &optional (b nil bp) (c nil cp))
  (declare (ignore a b bp c cp)))

(defun foo (a &optional (b nil bp) (c nil cp))
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (cond (cp (funcall #'bar a b c))
        (bp (funcall #'bar a b))
        (t (funcall #'bar a))))
```

```
CL-USER> (time (loop repeat 1000000 do (foo 1 2 3)))
Evaluation took:
  0.015 seconds of real time
  0.017203 seconds of total run time (0.017148 user, 0.000055 system)
  113.33% CPU
  41,186,554 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

Checking the arguments passed to `bar`:

```
(defun bar (a &optional (b nil bp) (c nil cp))
  (list a b bp c cp))
```

```
CL-USER> (foo 1 2 3)
(1 2 T 3 T)
CL-USER> (foo 1 2)
(1 2 T NIL NIL)
CL-USER> (foo 1)
(1 NIL NIL NIL NIL)
```

Comment: To think of it, using `cond` seems to be the best way to go about handling &optional arguments. Any other method (including using `nconc` with `list`) seems to require at least a linear number of steps to do any "set up". I'll wait a while before accepting this.

Comment: Is there an equivalent version for &key arguments? Supplying an &rest parameter can help avoid the consing, but changes the argument list displayed by slime/eldoc. OTOH, using `cond` would result in exponentially many branches.

Comment: The other alternative is to use compiler-macros, which is what I have been doing, but I wanted to know if there are other ways to achieve this.

Comment: The `&optional` and `&key` don't sit very well together, but for `&key` arguments alone you would need to test for each combination; I don't see any other way. That wouldn't be a big deal for small numbers of keyword arguments. You could probably write some macros to help you out there for larger numbers of arguments.

Comment: At some point with increasing number of &key arguments, I'm expecting that the number of cases will grow so large that the consing way could turn out to be the faster method.

Comment: My motivation for this was to ponder over how &optional and &key arguments passed to generic-functions on sbcl are passed to the methods with zero consing.

Comment: @digikar `(... &rest args &key a b c)` combined with suitable `ignore` declarations & `(apply ... args)` is the canonical approach for keywords.  If whatever tool is not smart enough to realise that the function takes exactly a fixed set of keywords in that case it needs to be made smarter: there's no purpose in deforming the program beyond recognition to help the tool limp along.

Comment: @tfb Gotta agree :) Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what `bar` and `foo` are actually supposed to do but what about:

```
(defun foo (a &optional (b nil bp))
  (declare (optimize speed))
  (funcall #'bar a (when bp b))) 

CL-USER> (time (loop repeat 1000000 do (foo 4 2)))
Evaluation took:
  0.005 seconds of real time
  0.005810 seconds of total run time (0.005804 user, 0.000006 system)
  120.00% CPU
  8,099,624 processor cycles
  0 bytes consed
```

Comment: This does not preserve the value of `bp` inside `bar`. The `funcall` version yields the value of `bp` as `t`, while the `apply` version yields `nil` when `b` is not supplied.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. I was just focused on the use of `list` inside your wrapper function which obviously causes the consing.